# MYSQL - #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails on existing table with data

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL database, I have two tables that I created and both tables have corresponding data. But I forgot to add constraint to the foreign key.

tables: hr_employees, hr_employee_types

So I decided to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE hr_employees
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_employee_employeetypes
FOREIGN KEY (employee_type_id) REFERENCES hr_employee_types(id);
```

I got this error:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`phrms`.`#sql-16e0_1cf`, CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_employeetypes` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_type_id`) REFERENCES `hr_employee_types` (`id`))

The fields exist and there are corresponding data.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: There are many reasons why the creation of an FK may fail - please add table definitions including their engines (show create table <tablename>)

Answer (score 0):

This probably mean that hr_employees has record that does not fit hr_employee_types or even null value in correspondent field.

Comment: @SKadakov - Some the values of employee_type_id in the hr_employees table are NULL. What do I do?

Comment: first update those to be valid, listed in hr_employee_types (update hr_employees set type = valid_type where type is null), then repeat alter, it should be successful.